# My Bool Tool doesn't work properly

Tags: boolean-modifier

I am trying to create a handguard for a gun but my bool tool doesn't work. If I try scaling the cubes up my cylinder disappears. I think something is wrong with my cylinder mesh but I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me?[image: The cylinder kinda ok][image: If I try to make my cubes bigger my cylinder disappears or nothing changes]

[image]

Comment: You can start by recalculating the normals on the boolean mesh! Red means they're inverted. Select All in Edit mode and hit Shift-N then try again. Having said that, the top image appears to show that it's working as expected so what exactly is your problem? If it still doesn't work you'll need to share your Blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately flipping the normals doesn't do anything. I want to cut my cylinder deeper however I don't know why It doesn't work properly. I have uploaded my file but I have also sent the link here. https://blend-exchange.com/b/J3Bvb0sX/

Comment: can u pls provide a blend file _with_ the bool modifier?

Comment: @Chris He's uploaded the Blend file. I suspect that part of the problem may be because he's trying to cut a cylinder created with an unapplied screw modifier, however it's still giving odd results even with the modifier applied to both cylinders. Not sure why he's not using a simple cylinder with one end scaled down slightly, but what do I know...

Comment: I have uploaded new file with bool tool. (link: https://blend-exchange.com/b/PePq40r7) I am trying to repeat work from https://www.artstation.com/learning/courses/OzX/introduction-concepting-in-blender/chapters/9eJ8/boolean-practice-handguard (timing 1:16) but I can't figure out where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add subdivisions to your mesh (I subdivided it 5 times, but more is better) and also, for performance, you can activate the fast solver on boolean modifier.

[image: Subdivision to mesh]

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It's kinda working but I still can't figure out why it works so strangely.

Comment: good idea from Leonardo :) for me it worked with fast and 3 subdivisions:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umgwy.jpg

Comment: for me - it sounds like a bug - you could try filing a bug report, but they might say "it only works with applied modifiers" but maybe worth a try ;)